# Necesito agrupar por un solo campo SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo que hacer lo siguiente

```
/** PRIMER CAMPO - TRANSACCION **/

/** SEGUNDO CAMPO - DEBITO SALDO POR TRANSACCION**/

select TransaccionId,SUM(NetAmount) as debito from TablaPrincipal where Id_movimiento = 1 group by TransaccionId (RESULTADO QUE DEBERIA DAR)


/** TERCER CAMPO -  CREDITO SALDO POR TRANSACCION**/

select TransaccionId,SUM(NetAmount) as credito from TablaPrincipal where Id_movimiento = 2 group by TransaccionId  (RESULTADO QUE DEBERIA DAR)


/** CUARTO CAMPO - CANTIDAD DE CUENTAS POR TRANSACCION **/

select TransaccionId, COUNT(AccountCode) as CantidadCuentas from TablaPrincipal group by TransaccionId  (RESULTADO QUE DEBERIA DAR)


/** QUINTO CAMPO -  CANTIDA DE FECHAS EFECTIVAS POR TRANSACCION **/

select  TransaccionId, COUNT(EffectiveDate) as CantidadFechas from TablaPrincipal group by TransaccionId  (RESULTADO QUE DEBERIA DAR)


/** ULTIMO CAMPO - FECHA DE CREACION DE LA TRANSACCION
```

yo hice esta query:

```
select TransaccionId, 
(select COUNT(AccountCode) from TablaPrincipal) as CantidadCuentas,
(select SUM(NetAmount) from TablaPrincipal where Id_movimiento = 1) as debito,
(select SUM(NetAmount) from TablaPrincipal where Id_movimiento = 2) as credito,
(select COUNT(EffectiveDate) from TablaPrincipal) as CantidadFechas,
CreatedDate
from TablaPrincipal
group by TransaccionId, CreatedDate
```

El problema es el siguiente  me trae los resultados totales de la tabla en cada columna donde estan hechas las subconsultas y no por transaccion (PRIMER CAMPO) como se desea.

> Tengo las subconsultas hechas que la pueden ver mas arriba pero nose
>   como integrarla a la query que hice.

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te falta nada más poner un **WHERE** dentro de la subconsulta, para poder filtrar los registros que sea igual a **TransaccionId**.

Este ejemplo es una solución:

```
SELECT tp.TransaccionId,
(
   SELECT COUNT(sub.AccountCode) FROM TablaPrincipal sub WHERE sub.TransaccionId=tp.TransaccionId
) AS CantidadCuentas,
(
   SELECT SUM(sub.NetAmount) FROM TablaPrincipal sub WHERE sub.TransaccionId=tp.TransaccionId AND Id_movimiento = 1
) AS debito,
(
   SELECT SUM(sub.NetAmount) FROM TablaPrincipal sub WHERE sub.TransaccionId=tp.TransaccionId AND Id_movimiento = 2
) AS credito,
(
   SELECT COUNT(sub.EffectiveDate) FROM TablaPrincipal sub WHERE sub.TransaccionId=tp.TransaccionId
) AS CantidadFechas,
tp.CreatedDate
FROM TablaPrincipal tp
GROUP BY tp.TransaccionId, tp.CreatedDate;
```

Comment: Buenisimo era lo que necesitaba. GRACIAS!